# has_many :through questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I was previously using has_and_belongs_to_many, and have converted to has_many :through.  Here's how it looks for a list of games that can have many users playing.  With this, I can do game.users and user.games....:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :game_users, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :users, :through => :game_users, :uniq => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :game_users, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :games, :through => :game_users, :uniq => true
end

class GameUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And my database migration for the join table:

```
create_table :game_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.column :game_id, :integer
      t.column :user_id, :integer
      t.column :player_index, :integer
    end
```

I'm not quite sure I get all this, please help me check my facts:

1. Is the dependent => :destroy correct?  I want the 'game_users' join table entry to be deleted if either the game or the user is destroyed - but I don't want users to be deleted if games are deleted and vice versa..... ?
2. The uniq field is supposed to say that games contain only unique users, and the users only contain unique games.  Is that correct?
3. The database migration as before has :id => false.  Is that still the right thing to do?  I tried in the console destroying a game, and got complaints about the missing id... so I'm guessing not and trying to understand why.

I find rails active record associations very confusing.  I guess they aren't supposed to be!

Comment: Your usage of :dependent => :destroy is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: Yes, that's correct

2: From the [documentation on uniq](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many):

> If true, duplicates will be omitted
>   from the collection. Useful in
>   conjunction with :through.

So, yes, if you aim is not get the same game in User's games-collection nor the same user in Game's users-collection, that's correct. It's all explained [here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/5/6/through-gets-uniq).

It will not, however, prevent duplicate GameUsers from being created. For that, you'd need to use [validates_ uniqueness _of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) in the GameUser-model:

```
class GameUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :game_id, :scope => :user_id
end
```

3: No, you don't want to use :id => false any more. By switching from has_and_belongs_to_many to has_many :through, you have promoted your many-to-many join-table to a full model - GameUser - which requires its own id.

While it is old, [this](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/2/28/association-goodness) is still a good article for understanding has_many :through.